# Как взять из страницы json конкретное число?

Tags: python, json

Нужно взять из страницы - https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json одно конкретное число, к примеру пункт 17(российский рубль). Как это можно сделать?

Comment: нужно взять число rate, то есть 0.48821 формата float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот Вам решение с использованием библиотеки `requests` и метода `json()`. Очень лаконично и просто.

```python
import requests

# Отправляем GET запрос
response = requests.get("https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json")

# Декодируем содержимое JSON
data = response.json()

# Находим нужный элемент
rate = None
for item in data:
    if item["cc"] == "RUB":
        rate = item["rate"]
        break

# Вывод результата
print(rate)
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!!

Comment: Успехов в Ваших проектах :)